# Any difference between "testing out" and "testing"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, idioms, phrasal-verbs

Is there a difference (in the meaning) between

> I've been **testing out** cameras...

and

> "I've been **testing** cameras..."

How (if at all) does the word "**out**" change the meaning of the verb?

And which one to use for describing when you have being doing tests of different cameras.

Answer (score 1):

From these definitions and my own sense, **test out** implies *practical* testing along the lines of *trying out, exploring,* or  *putting something to the test*. *Testing out* may also imply something less formal or rigorous than *testing*. You might *test* cameras for a magazine review (with your qualitative and quantitative results) and cursorily *test out* models at the store when shopping for one.

> **test** (v.)
>
> To subject to a test of any kind; to try, put to the proof; to
> ascertain the existence, genuineness, or quality of. **to test out**,
> to put (a theory, etc.) to a **practical test**.
>
> *To **test out** the value of radio publicity*.
>
> *Legal philosophers could back up these efforts by **testing out** some of their theories with research projects.* OED

**test out** (v.)

> (transitive) **To try or experiment with (something or someone) in order
> to see if it works, is true, or is successful.**
>
> *You will also have to **test out** any HTML code or Java applets that you include, and you will have to **test** the whole site once it is published to a server.*
>
> *Poland **tested** England **out** with their intensity and physical commitment but Southgate's side stood strong while also having to deal with a crowd of 56,212 made up entirely of home support.*
>
> (transitive) **To
> explore (something one has little experience with), especially to do
> so in a safe environment.**
>
> (transitive) To explore how (someone)
> responds to something; To feel someone out.
>
> (intransitive) To
> demonstrate a certain result in a test, especially a successful
> result.
>
> (intransitive) To pass a placement test that enables one to
> avoid taking a course. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/test_out)

> To put to test or proof: **TRY —often used with out** [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/test)